# »Was für eine Stadt« vs. »welche Stadt«

Tags: difference, interrogative

What’s the difference between *was für eine* and *welche* in the following context?

> Was für eine Stadt hat dir auf deiner Weltreise am besten gefallen?
>
> Welche Stadt hat dir auf deiner Weltreise am besten gefallen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beide sind richtig, aber die Bedeutung ist unterschiedlich.

> Welche Stadt hat dir auf deiner Weltreise am besten gefallen?

Hier wird nach einer bestimmten Stadt gefragt (*Castrop-Rauxel*)

> Was für eine Stadt hat dir auf deiner Weltreise am besten gefallen?

Das hier klingt schon etwas seltsam, es wird nach Eigenschaften der Lieblingsstadt gefragt. Falls man sich die Stadt in einem Ratespiel abfragen lassen will, wäre der Satz aber verwendbar. (*Eine stinkende Stadt.*)

Der zweite Satz wäre sinnvoller als:

> Was für Städte haben dir auf deiner Weltreise am besten gefallen?

Hier ist die Antwort dann entweder eine Kategorie (*seelenlose Vororte*) oder eine Liste (*Bielefeld, Detroit, Ordos, Pjöngjang*)

Answer (score 0):

Geht beides.

(1) ist meiner Meinung nach umgangssprachlich(er), zumindest weniger präzise, da es genau genommen *nach der Art der Stadt* statt direkt nach der Stadt fragt. Eine richtige, aber sinnlose Antwort wäre darauf auch *eine große*. (2) kann man eigentlich nur mit z. B. „Rom“ beantworten.

Comment: Also sinnlos wäre die Antwort nicht

Comment: Sinnlos in dem Sinne, dass sie die Frage nicht dem Sinn nach sinnig beantwortet?

Comment: Achso, so macht das schon eher SInn.