# Was/welche understanding the difference?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I am starting with German and my English isn't fluent; anyway, here goes the question:

Is it "the same" to say: **Was für Sprachen sprichst du?** Or do you say: **Welche ...** when trying to say: **What languages do you speak**?

Comment: [Was für ein/ welche](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/37460/1224) ### [»Was für eine Stadt« vs. »welche Stadt«](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28595/1224)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Was Sprachen sprichst du?

kann man nicht sagen, aber

```
Was für Sprachen sprichst du?
```

Gewählter ist:

```
Welche Sprachen sprichst du?
```

und sollte im schriftlichen Ausdruck verwendet werden. "Was für Sprachen ..." eignet sich aber in der Hochsprache auch, wenn man mit einer Antwort rechnet wie "romanische Sprachen, arabische Sprachen, ...".

Answer (score 1):

"Was" means "what" and "welche" means "which."

In German, you can only say "Welche Sprachen sprichst du?" between the two. (Which languages do you speak?)

You cannot use "Was" (alone that is) in this context, even though that would be acceptable in English. If you want to use the "Was" form you need to say, "Was **für** Sprachen sprichst du?"

Comment: Nice answer too. Danke